# Cropping JS libraries do not work in Election

Tags: electron, cropperjs, react-image-crop

I am trying to add a simple image cropping functionality in my Electron app. I want something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6).

I have tried [react-image-crop](https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop#example) and [react-cropper](https://github.com/react-cropper/react-cropper), but both did not work.

With the latter library, I simply did:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Cropper from 'react-cropper';
import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';

const ImageCrop = () => {
  const [upImg, setUpImg] = useState();

  const onSelectFile = e => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => setUpImg(reader.result));
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={onSelectFile} />
      </div>
      <Cropper src={upImg} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageCrop;
```

The result looks like the following and I was not able to select the area.

[image]

With the former library, it only displays an orange frame around the image and does not allow cropping it.
[image]

I imagine some JS functionality is somehow not working in Electron, but I do not know what exactly is going on here. Any help would be appreciated to explain it and make it work.

Comment: I would guess there is an issue with the CSS for those libraries. You could try manually locating the CSS files for the libraries and seeing if that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@kyleawayan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030246/cropping-js-libraries-do-not-work-in-election/68752693#comment118483396_67030246) is right.

You just have to manually include the CSS file into your HTML.

I was using an `index.html` file with Electron, so I had to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css" />
```

to the `<head>` of my HTML.